Datatable is not letting the page redirect
I have a datatable that is loading data from a ajax source, and data is populated through mysqli in that ajax source when it is fetched, the issue is, it takes some time to load the data as there are about 8000+ rows, but until the data is being loaded I am not able to use any button to redirect to any other page, it completes the ajax call then lets me do anything else on the page even if that is not related to the datatable
how do I fix that?
  function applyFeatherIcons() {
        feather.replace();
      }
    let tableDom="";
    tableDom+="\n<'row'<'col-12'P>>";
    tableDom+="\n<'row'<'col-sm-12 col-md-4 text-center text-md-start mg-sm-b-10'B><'col-sm-6 col-md-4 text-center align-self-center'l><'col-sm-6 col-md-4'f>>";
    tableDom+="\n<'row'<'col-12'tr>>";
    tableDom+="\n<'row'<'col-sm-12 col-md-5'i><'col-sm-12 col-md-7'p>>\n";
    let vouchtbl=$("#receipt_table").DataTable({
    'ajax': {
    "url": '/accounts_receivables/assets/data/receipts_data.php',
    "type": "POST",
    "data":{
      t:'variable_to_fetch_data'
    }
    },
    responsive: true,
    processing: true,
    deferRender: true,
    dom: tableDom,
    buttons: [{
          extend: "copy",
          className: "btn btn-sm pd-x-15 btn-primary btn-uppercase",
          exportOptions: {
                          columns: "thead th:not(.noExport)"
                      }
      }, {
          extend: "csv",
          className: "btn btn-sm pd-x-15 btn-primary btn-uppercase",
          exportOptions: {
                          columns: "thead th:not(.noExport)"
                      }
      }, {
          extend: "excel",
          className: "btn btn-sm pd-x-15 btn-primary btn-uppercase",
          exportOptions: {
                          columns: "thead th:not(.noExport)"
                      }
      }, {
          extend: "pdfHtml5",
          className: "btn btn-sm pd-x-15 btn-primary btn-uppercase",
          exportOptions: {
                          columns: "thead th:not(.noExport)"
                      }
      }, {
          extend: "print",
          className: "btn btn-sm pd-x-15 btn-primary btn-uppercase",
          exportOptions: {
                          columns: "thead th:not(.noExport)"
                      }
      }],
      lengthMenu: [
          [10, 25, 50, 75, -1],
          [10, 25, 50, 75, "All"]
      ],
      searchPanes: {
          cascadePanes: true,
          viewTotal: true,
          initCollapsed: true
      },
      language: {
          searchPanes: {
              count: "{total} found",
              countFiltered: "{shown} / {total}"
          },
          sSearch: '<span>Search: </span>',
          lengthMenu: '_MENU_ Receipts/page'
      },
      drawCallback: function() {
    applyFeatherIcons();
  }
});
$(function () {
  vouchtbl.draw();
  applyFeatherIcons();
});

I tried the deferRender option as suggested in the datatable documentation but that didnt help at all
